# Does OpenCL C compiler simplify math expressions?

Tags: c, performance, assembly, opencl

I am making a fractal generator and it needs to be really fast. Currently, a line of OpenCL C is being generated based on a user formula:

```
// User inputs z^2 + c + z^2 for example, generating this line of code:
z = cpow(z, 2) + c + cpow(z, 2);
```

My question is, when this line is compiled into assembly, will it execute the `cpow(z, 2)` calculation twice to compute the expression, or is OpenCL C optimised to only do that calculation once, and reuse that result for when it comes across the second `cpow(z, 2)`?

Comment: This depends on compiler optimizations, I don't think it has anything to do with OpenCL.

Comment: You could just look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: If optimisation are enabled, then yes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination

Comment: Look at the assembly yourself (https://godbolt.org/z/nrx1n7G71), and yes GCC with `-O3` can reuse the result because `cpow` (normally) doesn't have any side effect.

Comment: It _will_ optimize. But what about using: `z = 2 * cpow(z, 2) + c` to be sure?

Comment: @CraigEstey I think the code is supplied by a user at runtime, so OP doesn't have control over it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General rule, for any programming language: **Never trust the compiler to do any optimization for you.**

For certain simple things, you can be sure that the OpenCL compiler will optimize. Examples:

- `float x = y + (2.0f/3.0f + 4.0f);` // the compiler will pre-compute arithmetic with literals, as long as it does not alter the order of operations, and in assembly you will get only a single addition. So use brackets!
- `if(x<y) x = 4; else x = 5;` // the compiler will eliminate branching here and use the same assembly as for the ternary operator
- `float y = a*x+c;` // the compiler will compressed this in a single fused-multiply-add (FMA) instruction that does both the Multiplikation and the addition in a single clock cycle
- `for(int i=0; i<8; i++) x = x%y;` // the compiler will unroll the loop, so no clock cycles are wasted for incrementing i
- `float x = some complicated arithmetic; but then x is never used;` // the compiler will delete x and all arithmetic that is used to compute its value

But still there is many pitfalls - small details like in the first example not writing brackets - that lead to the compiler not optimizing to the full extent. You can experiment with https://godbolt.org/ to see what works and what doesn't. In OpenCL with Nvidia GPUs, you can generate PTX assembly and look into that.

Also the compiler is not too smart and does not always generate perfectly optimized assembly. In your example, the safe way for ideal performance - regardless of compiler settings - would be to just write it in an optimized manner:

```
z = 2*z*z+c; // The pow function is way slower than just a multiplication. In OpenCL, the compiler here will see a*b+c and compress that into a FMA instruction. So 1 multiplication and 1 FMA for this line.
```

A typical trick is also to use temporary variables for redundant terms in equations, and then just insert the variable whereever the term is occurring.

Besides suboptimal performance if the compiler does not optimize properly, with floating-point arithmetic you may also get suboptimal accuracy through larger round-off error, as that depends on what numbers you add and in which order. You should control and optimize this manually in the code; usually the compiler then does not change the order of operations.

Comment: In your first example, `y + 2.0f/3.0f + 4.0f`, https://godbolt.org/z/zze58ba7c shows clang is only allowed to re-associate `(y+2.f/3f) + 4.0f` to `y + (2.f/3f + 4.0f)` if you compile with `-ffast-math`.  Otherwise the `y+0.66666...f` temporary, and the rounding it introduces, has to actually exist before doing another add.  Does OpenCL always imply `-ffast-math`?

Comment: Maybe your first sentence is too strong. I do always check the compiler output for performance-critical code, but there are some obvious cases that you can trust the compiler to do certain optimizations.

Comment: @Peter Cordes you're right, usually the compiler does not alter the order of operations., so brackets are encouraged to pre-compute literals. I think without brackets, the OpenCL compiler simplifies this only with `-cl-fast-relaxed-math`.

Comment: @xiver77 . Nevertheless there is many pitfalls, like the one pointed out by  
Peter Cordes, with not putting literals in brackets. Another prime example is vectorization, where the tiniest deviation from the criteria makes your code not compile vectorized.